# How to use HTML5 input types in JSP using Struts2 tags

Tags: html, jsp, input, struts2

I have to take *age* as input from a JSP.

For this HTML5 provides:

```
<input type="number">
```

What is the equivalent tag for this in Struts2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version **2.3.7** on:

```xml
<s:textfield type="number" />
```

From [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/textfield.html):

> type:     Specifies the html5 type element to display. e.g. text, email, url

Comment: I follwed that, then the resultant html is `<input type="text" name="registerBean.age" value="0" id="registerOphthalmologist_registerBean_age" type="number"/>`. the tag is containing two 'type' arguments.

Comment: Which struts version do you have ? You need one of the latest

Comment: I'm using Struts 2.3.4.1 and having the same issue.

Comment: @anyulled I've made a search and you're right, it's from 2.3.7:  https://github.com/apache/struts/commit/b84a1a9e9cec557cb70b06489fc3dc81992c4f3d#diff-7bb3d79cd1e313859c5e0e1d0a7d2199R94